# Trouble with delegation, my delegate is always nil, tvOS, swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicollectionview, tvos

I'm working on a netflix style app for tvOS and I've followed some tutorials and I've done my share of stackOverflow research. Which has been very helpful, it's actually how I found the delegate solution I'm trying to implement. With the problem I'm having now, most of what I've found on here reference different popup views or containers. That's not exactly what my issue is so I'm having a hard time. I'm also pretty much brand spanking new iOS, tvOS, Swift in general, most of my previous dev work was JS, AS3, Classic ASP, PHP...

To the point: I have a view structure as shown:[view structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGxXN.png)

I have a class for my main ViewController, called ListViewController, 
I have a class for my table view cell called ListTableViewCell, the reference is "rowCell" as you see in the image. 
I have a calls for my collection view cell called ListViewCell.

My ListTableViewCell is structured like this :

```
import UIKit

protocol ListViewDelegate {
    func updatePreview (name: String,runtTime:Int,description:String,level:String)
}

class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    var delegate:ListViewDelegate?
    var list:List?

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}

extension ListTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource { 

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (self.list?.MediaObjects.count != nil){
            return (self.list?.MediaObjects.count)!
        }else{
               return 0
        }

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListViewCell
            let list = self.list!
            let media = list.MediaObjects
            cell.mediaLabel.text = media[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    }

    override func shouldUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
        let list = self.list!
        let cell: UICollectionViewCell = context.nextFocusedView as! UICollectionViewCell
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath? = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        if  let path = indexPath{
            let name =  list.MediaObjects[path.row].name
            let runTime = list.MediaObjects[path.row].runTime
            let description = list.MediaObjects[path.row].description
            let level = list.MediaObjects[path.row].level
            print(path.row)
            if let del = delegate {
                del.updatePreview(name,runtTime:runTime,description:description,level:level)
            }
        }

        return true
    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

        return true
    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let playerVC = PlayerViewController()
        playerVC.videoFile = (list?.MediaObjects[indexPath.row].fileURI)!
        playerVC.playVideo()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



}
```

The delegate is always nil.

here is the code for my UIViewController class -

```
import UIKit

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ListViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var lists = [List]()

    @IBOutlet weak var videoDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoLevelLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoRunTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoTitleLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let listLoader = loadLists()
        listLoader.loadData { (dataLoaded:Bool, lists:[List]) in
            if (dataLoaded == true){
                    print("complete \(self.lists.count)")
                    self.lists = lists
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
            }else {
                print("data load error")
            }

        }

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.lists.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let row = self.lists[section]
        return "\(row.name)"
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rowCell") as! ListTableViewCell
        let list = self.lists[indexPath.row]
        cell.list = list

        return cell
    }

    func updatePreview(name: String,runtTime:Int,description:String,level:String) {
        print("delegage method called")
        self.videoLevelLabel.text = level
        self.videoTitleLabel.text = name
        self.videoDescriptionLabel.text = description
        self.videoRunTimeLabel.text = String(runtTime)


    }





}
```

This code is nowhere near production ready, I know that, no need to comment on how I'm handling optionals, etc... I'm already fully aware there other issues I need to clean up. Any feedback on code structure or better approaches or just "you're doing this all wrong" would be greatly appreciated but please keep comments on topic. My code works, I pull data in from my own Parse Server instance, I can navigate through the playlists and videos and programmatically call up the player and they will play. The only thing I'm having problems with is getting data to bubble back up to the VC so I can update the appropriate Outlets.

The app I am building will never be a production app, it's a proof of concept and a learning exercise. I generally don't ask questions on here because I'm pretty good at using the site to find answers I need but I'm stumped on this one.

[The UI Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/304jt.jpg)

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate?

Comment: Also, your delegate should be declared as `weak`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not assigning your delegate:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListViewCell
        let list = self.list!
        let media = list.MediaObjects
        cell.mediaLabel.text = media[indexPath.row].name
        cell.delegate = self // set delegate in your cellforItemAtIndexPath method
    return cell
}
```

Comment: So if I try to do this inside the extension on that class I get a member error. I think made this confusing by breaking up the class into different sections above. Let me re-paste my code all as one piece. I think you're right about what I have to do, but I don't know where to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the delegate. For the UITableViewController template the delegate & datasource are automatically set in interface builder.

Try to set the delegate and datasource either in interface builder or in code.

Comment: I've set delegates for the UICollectionView, It's delegate and it's datasource are both set to the UITableViewCell class I've created. I have that part working ok. I need to delegate the UITableViewCell back to the main ViewController though, I think, that's what I am trying to do here, because I thought this was the right way to do it... but maybe I need to set a delegate on the UICollectionViewCell back to the main ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand the question correctly; You have a view controller which has a tableview. The tableview cell has a collectionview in it. Whenever there is a focus update in the collection view, you want the callback to be sent back to view controller.

All you have to do is set the delegate variable which you have created in **tableview** cellForRow method in the view controller.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: ListTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self /// Setting the delegate so that view controller gets the callback for focus update

        return cell
    }
```